# Control (override) inline style using media query

Tags: jquery, html, css, media-queries

I have come across different questions here about media queries and inline style, but none of them covers what I want.

I am working on a small project where between the things I have to do is to change the main menu on mobile view to be something like `collapse/expand`

Anyway, I have this simple js to change the `display` of the menu on mobile view

```
  $("#toggler").click(
        function () {
            if ($("#navigation").css("display") == "none") {
                $("#navigation").css("display", "block");
            }
            else {
                $("#navigation").css("display", "none");
            }
        }
        );
```

and I have this `media query` to show the `toggler` btn when the mobile view `css` media query is active, and to hide the menu as well. The user then can press the `toggler` btn to open/show the menu.

```
 @media screen and (max-width:500px) {
        #navigation {
            display: none;
            width: 100%;
            float: none;
        }  
        #toggler {
            display: block;
        }
    }
```

Now, if the browser has the mobile view active and the user has pressed the `toggler` to show the menu then he pressed it again to hide it, the `#navigation` will have `display:none` as an-inline style, then if the user resizes the browser again back to its normal view (greater than 500px) what happens is that the media query won't change (override) the inline `display:none` back to `display:block`

any suggestions how to change inline style through `media queries`?

Comment: instead of pushing the css into the element, can you just add/remove a classname that forces the changes you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of changing the inline styles, you can toggle the class on the element. [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ladar/1/edit)

JS

```
$("#toggler").click(function () {
   $("#navigation").toggleClass('unhidden');
})
```

CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width:500px) {
    #navigation {
        display: none;
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
    }
    #navigation.unhidden {
        display:block;
    }  
    #toggler {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is much easier to do

Comment: How would you account for using animations through this method?

Comment: @LukeA.Leber you basically bind to transitionEnd and change the class in the handler. There is some discussion about how reliable that event is in some mobile browsers. I tend to stay away from animations, but iirc using vendor prefixes handle 99.9% of the compatibility issues.